# Parsing binary data in Python 3 v.s. Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a piece of code that reads raw binary data and outputs the data into a csv file. The code runs perfectly in Python 2, but would not work in Python 3. In Python 3, A new output file would be created, but no data would be written into it. I have tried to modify it but I just couldn't figure out how to make it work in Python 3x...

Please help me to make this code work in Python 3.

I think the problem is caused by the different handling of "str" and "bytes" between Python 2 and 3. I read the document of "Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3" (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) and tried many things that I didn't even know if they made sense, and of course they didn't work... Please see below the codes.

```py
import gzip
import struct
import csv

def read_binary_file(size,bin_data_operator):
    read = bin_data_operator.read(size);
    return read;

def add_order_no_mpid(msg):
    msg_type = 'A';
    temp = struct.unpack('>4s6sQcI8cI',msg);
    new_msg = struct.pack('>s4s2s6sQsI8sI',msg_type,temp[0],'\x00\x00',temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4],''.join(list(temp[5:13])),temp[13]);
    val = struct.unpack('>sHHQQsI8sI',new_msg);
    val = list(val);
    val[8] = float(val[8]);
    val[8] = val[8]/10000;
    return val;

def add_order_with_mpid(msg):
    msg_type = 'F';
    temp = struct.unpack('>4s6sQcI8cI4c',msg);
    new_msg = struct.pack('>s4s2s6sQsI8sI4s',msg_type,temp[0],'\x00\x00',temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4],''.join(list(temp[5:13])),temp[13],''.join(list(temp[14:18])));
    val = struct.unpack('>sHHQQsI8sI4s',new_msg);
    val = list(val);
    val[8] = float(val[8]);
    val[8] = val[8]/10000; 
    return val;

def order_executed_message(msg):
    msg_type = 'E';
    temp = struct.unpack('>4s6sQIQ',msg);
    new_msg = struct.pack('>s4s2s6sQIQ',msg_type,temp[0],'\x00\x00',temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4]);
    val = struct.unpack('>sHHQQIQ',new_msg);
    val = list(val);
    return val;

bin_data = gzip.open('input_binary_data.txt.gz','rb');
out_file = open('output_file.csv','wb');
writer = csv.writer(out_file);
message_type = bin_data.read(1);

while message_type:

    if message_type == "A":
        message = read_binary_file(35,bin_data);
        parsed_data = add_order_no_mpid(message);
        writer.writerow(parsed_data)
    elif message_type == "F":
        message = read_binary_file(39,bin_data);
        parsed_data = add_order_with_mpid(message);
        writer.writerow(parsed_data)
    elif message_type == "E":
        message = read_binary_file(30,bin_data);
        parsed_data = order_executed_message(message);
        writer.writerow(parsed_data)

    message_type = bin_data.read(1);

bin_data.close();
out_file.close();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to make this work in Python 3, but I don't know how...

Comment: What specific problems did you encounter? Please take a moment to read [ask] for some tips to improve your question so that you will get the help that you need.

Comment: In Python 3, A new output file would be created, but no data would be written into it.

Comment: This is mostly about trying to figure out why you are getting different behavior when porting to Python 3. That means you need to start debugging your code to isolate the problem. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: You have a lot of code, something in it does not work. Try to isolate parts which don't work, e.g. by comparing behaviour of different part of your code in py2 (where it works) and in py3 (where it does not).

Comment: At the very least, can you post a sample input file and expected output file? Three records, one of each type.